# How to convert pptx files to jpg or png (for each slide) on linux?

Tags: linux, jpeg, converters, powerpoint, libreoffice

I want to convert a powerpoint presentation to multiple images. I already installed LibreOffice on my server and converting docx to pdf is no problem. pptx to pdf conversion does not work. I used following command line:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf filename.pptx
```

Is there es way to convert pptx to pngs immediately or do I have to convert it to pdf first and then use ghostscript or something?

And what about the quality settings? Is there a way to choose the resolution of the resulting images?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
According to [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/388350/convert-ppt-to-jpg) I was able to convert a pdf to images with the simple command line:

```
convert <filename>.pdf <filename>.jpg
```

(I guess you need LibreOffice and ImageMagick for it but not sure about it - worked on my server)

But there are still the problems with the pptx-to-pdf convert.

Thanks to googling and Sebastian Heyn's help I was able to create some high quality images with this line:

```
convert -density 400 my_filename.pdf -resize 2000x1500 my_filename%d.jpg
```

Please be patient after using it - you still can type soemthing into the unix console but it's processing. Just wait a few minutes and the jpg files will be created.

For further information about the options check out this [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)

P.S.: The aspect ratio of a pptx file doesn't seem to be exactly 4:3 because the resulting image size is 1950x1500

Comment: The aspect ration of a PPTX file will depend on the PPTX file itself. It can be pretty much anything. The default for older versions of PPT has always been 10" x 7.5", or 1.3333... rather than the 1.3 aspect ratio you're seeing. The PPTX might be set up at a non-standard size though.

Comment: Ah ok, I was expecting 4:3 because it always looked like that and most beamers have just a resolution of 800x600 (4:3). Good to know. Thx!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After Installing unoconv and LibreOffice you can use:

```
unoconv --export Quality=100 filename.pptx filename.pdf
```

to convert your presentation to a pdf. For further options look [here](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/blob/master/doc/filters.txt).

Afterwards you can - as already said above - use:

```
convert -density 400 my_filename.pdf -resize 2000x1500 my_filename%d.jpg
```

to receive the images.

Comment: The link for further options moved [here](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv/blob/master/doc/filters.adoc).

Comment: `unoconv` doesn't provide high quality results.

Answer (score 7):

## Convertion PPTX to PNG/JPG

This solution requires **LibreOffice** ( `soffice` ) and **Ghostscript** ( `gs` )

```
sudo apt install libreoffice ghostscript
```

Then two steps:

1. **PPTX -> PDF**

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf prezentacja.pptx
```

2. **PDF -> PNG/JPG**

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -o slajd-%02d.png -r96 prezentacja.pdf
```

- `-o slajd-%02d.png` - output to file, %02d slajd number, two digits
- `-r96` - resolution:

  - 96 -> 1280x720
  - 144 -> 1920x1080

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about libreoffice, but afaik its the only program to deal with pptx files.

I found this http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/23851/converting-pptx-to-pdf-issue/

If you have pdfs you can use imagemagick to output any quality pictures

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how to convert pdf to jpgs. Now I just have to find out how to convert pptx to pdf and how to change the quality settings. Maybe your link is the answer to the pptx to pdf question :)

Comment: convert allows to add quality settings  convert -density 400 file.pdf -scale 2000x1000 hi-res%d.jpg

Comment: Yeah thx, I was already trying. But it's strange. The one option that worked was resize 250% but the images were blurry of course. I tried density, resample etc. but the console doesn't really react to it. I still can press enter and if I press the left arrow ^[[D appears. After pressing ctrl+c+enter I finally can use commands again. But no jpgs were created. It's really weird :( But  convert -density 400 MP.pdf -scale 2000x1500 hi-res%d.jpg should be the correct syntax...

Comment: Alright It works now. I was just too impatient. Normally you can't do anything in the Unix console while processing. But after the convert command line I could - Confusing but it worked :D